# Android rendering exception: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is giving me a **`Rendering Problem: Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout`** error every time it tries to render a view of mine.

My XML is [here](http://pastebin.com/GGgJGXDM)

When it throws that error, it will fail to render the view.

Any ideas why this is happening to me?

Comment: cut out the views one by one until you find the circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going through that full xml file but it's probably because two elements are referencing each other. Like viewA has layoutBelow ViewB and ViewB has layoutBelow viewA or something similar.